# GetComponent doesn't work, no error, not crashing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an issue when calling a GetComponent.
Here is the code where it's called :

```cs
switch (JsonUtility.FromJson<InBaseInstruction>(message).type) {
    case InInstructionType.Auth: {
        InAuthInstruction auth = JsonUtility.FromJson<InAuthInstruction>(message);

        // Testing stuff
        Debug.Log("Hello ?");

        if (gameObject.GetComponent<AuthController>() == null)
            Debug.Log("Auth Controller null");
        else
            Debug.Log("Not null");

        Debug.Log("Auth Result : " + auth.result.ToString());
        // Done testing

        GetComponent<AuthController>().AuthResultHandler(auth.result);
        return;
    }
}
```

I've double checked AuthController was on the same GameObject, it is.
I've tried null checking (see above), none of the two Logs show in console.
The only thing I see in my console is "Hello ?".
I've tried adding a Debug.Log after the whole switch (by changing the return; to a break;) to see if the switch is causing that, it's not. The log doesn't appear after "Hello ?".
Everything compiles just fine.

And that's the main issue, GetComponent is not throwing an error at all, the code just stops working from there. Nothing else is happening.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `gameObject` is probably `null` and the exception thrown by this piece of code is probably being eaten by an async/coroutine/lambda/`catch(Exception)` wrapper.

Do this to debug further.

```
try {
    switch (JsonUtility.FromJson<InBaseInstruction>(message).type) {
    case InInstructionType.Auth: {
        InAuthInstruction auth = JsonUtility.FromJson<InAuthInstruction>(message);

        // Testing stuff
        Debug.Log("Hello ?");

        if (gameObject.GetComponent<AuthController>() == null)
            Debug.Log("Auth Controller null");
        else
            Debug.Log("Not null");

        Debug.Log("Auth Result : " + auth.result.ToString());
        // Done testing

        GetComponent<AuthController>().AuthResultHandler(auth.result);
        return;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Debug.LogError(e);
}
```

Comment: You're a life saver mate, didn't know async could stop errors from showing. I added the try catch, and I now have an error that says "get_gameObject can only be called from the main thread." which makes sense. Your answer solves my question tho, thanks !

Comment: Oh, I learned something new as well with that error. Thanks :)

Comment: Here is the talk which taught me all the gotchas about writing async code in unity: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7eKi6NKri6I